# What is the probability that a given book will be returned within 6 days, if it has been borrowed 4 days ago

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

The entire question is as follows:

> Suppose at some public library, the patrons return the books after $4$, $5$, $6$, or $7$ days of borrowing with probability $0.1$, $0.2$, $0.3$, and $0.4$ respectively. They are also allowed to return the book to a different branch, which they do so with a probability of 0.5. If they return the book to a different branch, it takes 2 extra days for the book to be returned to this branch. Assume that the library is open every day and that nobody else is waiting for the book. Suppose that you enquire about a book on Monday evening. You find out that it was borrowed last Thursday. What is the probability that you'll have to wait until this Wednesday to get the book? You check every evening.

Let,

- B be the indicator variable to denote the number of days till you can borrow the book
- I be the indicator variable to denote whether or not the borrower will return the book to the different branch

So, we have to find $P(B = 6|B > 4)$

$$P(B = 6|B > 4) = \frac{P(B = 6 \text{ and } B > 4)}{P(B > 4)}$$

The numerator is obvious. The only possibility for $B=6$ and $B > 4$ is $B=6$. For the denominator, notice that 4 is the minimum number of days that the patron takes to return the book. So $P(B > 4)$ can also be written as $1-P(B = 4)$.

Also notice that for $B=6$, the patron could've either returned the book to this branch or the other branch. But for $B=4$, the patron must have returned the book to this branch. If the patron had returned the book to the other branch, considering the delay of 2 days, the patron would've had to return the book within 2 days of borrowing, which is not possible since the minimum number of days to return a book is 4.
So,
$$
\begin{align}
P(B = 6|B > 4) &= \frac{P(B = 6)}{1-P(B = 4)}\\
               &= \frac{P(B=6 | I=0)\cdot P(I=0) + P(B=6 | I=1)\cdot P(I=1)}{1-P(B=4)}\\
               &= \frac{0.3\cdot 0.5 + 0.1\cdot 0.5}{1-0.1\cdot 0.5}\\
               &= \frac{4}{19}
\end{align}
$$

Here is my doubt. In the denominator, to calculate $P(B=4)$ the author uses $P(B=4, I=0) = 0.1\cdot 0.5$. But, my intuition says that since we know that if $B=4$, $I$ can't be $1$, then $I$ should not be considered random but as a given. So, we should've used $P(B=4 | I = 0)=0.1$ to calculate $P(B=4)$.

With this change, the answer would've been $\frac{2}{9}$

I also do realize that the reasoning concludes that $P(B = 4 | I = 1) = 0$ and not that $P(B=4) = P(B=4 | I=0)$, but I just can't seem to understand why we're including $P(I=0)$ in that calculation since we know what $I$ is constant for that situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ill-posed.  To understand why, the author makes an implicit assumption that whether the borrower returns the book to a different branch is *independent* of the number of days the book was borrowed.  They do not need to be.  For instance, if $X$ is the number of days the book is borrowed and $I \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ is an indicator variable where the event $I = 1$ means the borrower returned the book to a different branch, then we could certainly have
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Pr[(X,I) = (x,i)] & x = 4 & x = 5 & x = 6 & x = 7 & \text{Total} \\
\hline
i = 0 & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.25 & 0.50 \\
i = 1 & 0.00 & 0.15 & 0.20 & 0.15 & 0.50 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 0.10 & 0.20 & 0.30 & 0.40 & 1.00 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
which is a valid joint probability mass function for $X, I$ that satisfies the given conditions of the problem.

But suppose we grant the independence assumption, and the joint mass function is:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\Pr[(X,I) = (x,i)] & x = 4 & x = 5 & x = 6 & x = 7 & \text{Total} \\
\hline
i = 0 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.15 & 0.20 & 0.50 \\
i = 1 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.15 & 0.20 & 0.50 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 0.10 & 0.20 & 0.30 & 0.40 & 1.00 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Then the random variable $B$ (which is *not* an indicator) which counts the number of days from when the book is checked out until it is *available*, is given by
$$B = X + 2I.$$
Thus the probability mass function for $B$ looks like this:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
b & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & \text{Total} \\
\hline
\Pr[B = b] & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.20 & 0.30 & 0.15 & 0.20 & 1.00 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Hence
$$\Pr[B = 6 \mid B > 4] = \frac{\Pr[B = 6]}{\Pr[B > 4]} = \frac{0.20}{1 - 0.05} = \frac{4}{19}.$$
This computation agrees with your approach, as it should.  Notice how the explicit calculation of the joint mass function of $(X,I)$ and the subsequent probability table for $B$ renders the need for the indicator function $I$ in the final calculation, because once we know how $B$ is distributed, there is no need to involve any other variables.  And this is also the key to understanding why the statement
$$\Pr[(B = 4) \cap (I = 0)] \overset{?}{=} (0.1)(0.5)$$
is wrong.  First of all, it confuses $B$ with $X$:  the former is how long we have to wait for the book to be available; the latter is how long it takes for the borrower to return the book.  They are not the same.  We assumed that $X$ and $I$ are independent, but $B = X + 2I$ is *not* independent of $I$.  Second, the consideration of $I$ is totally unnecessary, as we have just explained above.

Answer (score 1):

What the author has computed is the probability of the event:

> You'll have to wait to get the book **on this Wednesday** .

The probability of the given event:

> You'll have to wait **until this Wednesday** to get the book.

is computed as follows:

$$P(\color{blue}{B \le  6}|B > 4) = \frac{\color{blue}{P(B = 5)}+P(B = 6)}{1-P(B = 4)}$$

where $B$ denotes the number of days till the book can be barrowed from the specific branch.

To avoid **any confusion**, let us compute each probability based on the same method as follows:

$P(B=6)=P(B=6 | I=0)\cdot P(I=0) + P(B=6 | I=1)\cdot P(I=1)=0.3\cdot 0.5 + 0.1\cdot 0.5$

$P(B=5)=P(B=5 | I=0)\cdot P(I=0) + P(B=5 | I=1)\cdot P(I=1)=0.2\cdot 0.5 + \color{blue}{0}\cdot 0.5$

$\color{blue}{P(B=4)}=P(B=4 | I=0)\cdot P(I=0) + P(B=4 | I=1)\cdot P(I=1)=0.1\cdot 0.5 + \color{blue}{0}\cdot 0.5$

where $I$ is a 0-1 indicator variable that is 1 if the borrower returns the book to a different branch. Note that above we used the following fact: $$P(B=4 | I=1)=P(B=5 | I=1)=\color{blue}{0}.$$

Hence, the probability of that the book can be barrowed form the **specific** branch **until** this Wednesday is

$$P(B \le  6|B > 4) = \frac{0.2\cdot 0.5+0.3\cdot 0.5 + 0.1\cdot 0.5}{1-0.1\cdot 0.5}=\color{blue}{\frac{6}{19}}.$$